# Adaptive Threshold parameters confusion

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone please tell me what are the parameters in these Adaptive Threshold functions and how are they controlling black and white pixels.

```
cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation of `cv::adaptiveThreshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold)? I think that pretty much explains the parameters.

Comment: Yes i did. But I am still not clear about 11 and 2 in these functions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Python: cv2.adaptiveThreshold(src, maxValue, adaptiveMethod, thresholdType, blockSize, C[, dst]) → dst
```

Parameters:

```
src – Source 8-bit single-channel image.
dst – Destination image of the same size and the same type as src .
maxValue – Non-zero value assigned to the pixels for which the condition is satisfied. See the details below.
adaptiveMethod – Adaptive thresholding algorithm to use, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C or ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C . See the details below.
thresholdType – Thresholding type that must be either THRESH_BINARY or THRESH_BINARY_INV .
blockSize – Size of a pixel neighborhood that is used to calculate a threshold value for the pixel: 3, 5, 7, and so on.
C – Constant subtracted from the mean or weighted mean (see the details below). Normally, it is positive but may be zero or negative as well.
```

Taken from [here:](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) and it also explains the method in a lot more detail.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: @RickSmith http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html

Answer (score 4):

Add to the answer from GPPK.

The function transforms a grayscale image to a binary image according to the formulae:

- THRESH_BINARY

[image]

- THRESH_BINARY_INV

[image]

where T(x,y) is a threshold calculated individually for each pixel.

- For the method ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C , the threshold value T(x,y) is a mean of the blockSize x blockSize neighborhood of (x, y) minus C .
- For the method ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C , the threshold value T(x, y) is a weighted sum (cross-correlation with a Gaussian window) of the blockSize x blockSize neighborhood of (x, y) minus C . The default sigma (standard deviation) is used for the specified blockSize .